# Arranging Ten Inputted Numbers into Ascending and Descending order

Tags: c#, sorting

I want to create a program that lets me enter ten different numbers in ten different textboxes, then later on sort these inputted numbers into ascending OR descending order. The windows form application design has ten textboxes in it, a button named "Sort" (the button that will sort out the numbers depending on the radio button of your choice) and two radio buttons named "Ascending" and "Descending". The design also have ten labels, wherein the sorted out numbers will be displayed after the user clicked on the Sort button. However, I'm finding troubles regarding the actual coding itself, I considered using a nested for loop but couldn't handle the conditions. Now I've used an array supported with multiple if else statements.

Here's my C# windows form application codes :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Sort
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btnSort_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int num1, num2, num3, num4, num5, num6, num7, num8, num9, num10;
            num1 = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
            num2 = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
            num3 = int.Parse(textBox3.Text);
            num4 = int.Parse(textBox4.Text);
            num5 = int.Parse(textBox5.Text);
            num6 = int.Parse(textBox6.Text);
            num7 = int.Parse(textBox7.Text);
            num8 = int.Parse(textBox8.Text);
            num9 = int.Parse(textBox9.Text);
            num10 = int.Parse(textBox10.Text);


            if (radioButton1.Checked == true)
            {
                int[] numbers = { num1, num2, num3, num4, num5, num6, num7, num8, num9, num10 };
                //String[] display = { l1, l2, l3, l4, l5, l6, l7, l8, l9, l10 };
                Array.Sort(numbers);

                if (num1 <= num2)
                {
                    label12.Text = textBox1.Text;
                }
                else if (num2 <= num3)
                {
                    label13.Text = textBox2.Text;

                }
                else if (num3 <= num4)
                {
                    label14.Text = textBox3.Text;
                }
                else if (num4 <= num5)
                {
                    label15.Text = textBox4.Text;

                }
                else if (num5 <= num6)
                {
                    label16.Text = textBox5.Text;

                }
                else if (num6 <= num7)
                {
                    label21.Text = textBox6.Text;

                }
                else if (num7 <= num8)
                {
                    label20.Text = textBox7.Text;

                }
                else if (num8 <= num9)
                {
                    label19.Text = textBox8.Text;

                }
                else if (num9 <= num10)
                {
                    label18.Text = textBox9.Text;

                }
                else if (num10 <= num1)
                {
                    label17.Text = textBox10.Text;
                }
        }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, I've run it and it's not triggering the codes I've put in. So basically, it's not functioning. Same with the nested for loop I did, maybe the conditions weren't coded right back then much like this one.

Comment: It showed an error, I think... the btnSort_Click event should be left as is. I think the problem is inside my coding itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        List<TextBox> textBoxes = null;
        List<Label> labels = null;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            textBoxes = new List<TextBox>() { textBox1, textBox2, textBox3, textBox4, textBox5, textBox6, textBox7, textBox8, textBox9, textBox10 };
            labels = new List<Label>() { label1, label2, label3, label4, label5, label6, label7, label8, label9, label10 };

            for (int i = 0; i < textBoxes.Count; i++)
            {
                labels[i].Text = textBoxes[i].Text;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < labels.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                int iInt = int.Parse(labels[i].Text);
                for (int j = i + 1; j < labels.Count; j++)
                {
                    int jInt = int.Parse(labels[j].Text);
                    if (jInt < iInt)
                    {
                        iInt = int.Parse(labels[j].Text);
                        string temp = labels[i].Text;
                        labels[i].Text = labels[j].Text;
                        labels[j].Text = temp;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
​
```

Or this method

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        List<TextBox> textBoxes = null;
        List<int> numbers = new List<int>();
        List<Label> labels = null;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            textBoxes = new List<TextBox>() { textBox1, textBox2, textBox3, textBox4, textBox5, textBox6, textBox7, textBox8, textBox9, textBox10 };
            labels = new List<Label>() { label1, label2, label3, label4, label5, label6, label7, label8, label9, label10 };

            for (int i = 0; i < textBoxes.Count; i++)
            {
                 numbers.Add(int.Parse(textBoxes[i].Text));
            }
            numbers = numbers.OrderBy(x => x).ToList();
            for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Count; i++)
            {
                labels[i].Text = numbers.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
​
```

Comment: I want to display the sorted numbers on another set of labels when i clicke the sort button, not textboxes. So will I just replace "int jInt = int.Parse(textBoxes[j].Text);" to label? here's the interface btw http://i.imgur.com/Eti4Sp8.jpg

Comment: The code seems appropriate and logical, but I want the numbers from the textbox to be arranged and displayed on the labels when the user clicks on the radio button sequences first (choosing whether to arrange it to ascending or descending) then click on the sort button to execute the command. Like in the interface http://i.imgur.com/Eti4Sp8.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. Here I'm using Entity Framework for using functions OrderBy and OrderByDescending to sort the data as and when reqired.

```
private void btnSort_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int num1, num2, num3, num4, num5, num6, num7, num8, num9, num10;
            num1 = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
            num2 = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
            num3 = int.Parse(textBox3.Text);
            num4 = int.Parse(textBox4.Text);
            num5 = int.Parse(textBox5.Text);
            num6 = int.Parse(textBox6.Text);
            num7 = int.Parse(textBox7.Text);
            num8 = int.Parse(textBox8.Text);
            num9 = int.Parse(textBox9.Text);
            num10 = int.Parse(textBox10.Text);

            var inputList = new List<int>();
            inputList.Add(num1);
            inputList.Add(num2);
            inputList.Add(num3);
            inputList.Add(num4);
            inputList.Add(num5);
            inputList.Add(num6);
            inputList.Add(num7);
            inputList.Add(num8);
            inputList.Add(num9);
            inputList.Add(num10);

        inputList.OrderBy(order =>order);
        inputList.OrderByDescending(order =>order);

    }
```

You might have to import the Entity Framework using nuGet Packages and then try this code. Hope my reply answered your question.